# How do I write a multikey query in MongoDb and C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In our Mongo database we have a collection indexed by "StoreId" and "ItemId". The following query brings back all combinations of product stores (total of 9 documents) included in the "In" list.

```
var productQuery = Query.In("ItemId", new BsonArray(new List<int> {1, 2, 3}));
var storeQuery = Query.In("StoreId", new BsonArray(new List<int> {1, 2, 3}));
var queryToBringNineDocuments = Query.And(productQuery, storeQuery);
```

How do I write a query that brings me back documents with keys in the following item-store tuple list?

```
var neededProductStores = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2),
    new Tuple<int, int>(1, 3),
    new Tuple<int, int>(2, 1),
    new Tuple<int, int>(3, 2)
};

var queryToBringFourDocuments = ?;
```

Comment: Can you clarify here, is that 4 documents or one document with an array of 4 items inside of it? MongoDB can only return documents, not "sub-documents".

Comment: I have 9 separate documents for each combination of item-store. I need to get a subset of those documents. I can do this in multiple queries but wondering if there was a way with a single query.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that there is only one way currently -- create extra field that will contains both ids and query on it

So in your c# class which you store to database you can have:

```
public string ProductStoreId 
{
  get 
  {
     return string.Format("{0}_{1}",ItemId, StoreId);
  }
  set { } //empty set means that it will be stored to database
}
```

Then your query will be:

```
var query = Query.In("ProductStoreId", new BsonArray(new List<string> {"1_2", "1_3",.. }));
```

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done with an OR query that accumulates AND queries.  It could get pretty ugly if you have a lot of combinations, though.

```
var neededProductStores = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
                                {
                                    new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2),
                                    new Tuple<int, int>(1, 3),
                                    new Tuple<int, int>(2, 1),
                                    new Tuple<int, int>(3, 2)
                                };

  IMongoQuery[] queries =(from t in neededProductStores
       select Query.And(Query.EQ("ItemId", t.Item1), Query.EQ("StoreId", t.Item2))).ToArray<IMongoQuery>();
  var queryToBringFourDocuments = Query.Or(queries);
```